# Windows drive crashed on dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, and Ubuntu 16.xx with Xfce4 desktop.

Windows was installed first on a 120 GB SSD.

Ubuntu was installed second on a 240 GB SSD and I was using Grub2 to handle the dual boot.

The Windows SSD died, and its data is completely unrecoverable. I have backups of all the data I care about.

I bought a new SSD and reinstalled Windows, all done with the Ubuntu drive disconnected.  But I don't know how to get the dual boot back with my existing Ubuntu install.

How do I get my dual boot setup again without losing my Ubuntu install?

Answer (score 0):

Hello there & welcome to ask ubuntu!

The problem here as you've successfully figured out thus far, is that your boot-loader doesn't have entries for all the operating systems installed in your computer's drives.

Open a terminal and type    `sudo grub-update`.

It's quite likely this will resolve the problem. You can find more info about this method [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwOg2tt76Rg).

If the problem persists after sudo grub-update you can use [os-prober](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KU6QC8UDyoI) (official package here / `sudo apt-get install os-prober`)

Otherwise, you can deep-dive into linux and do it manually (it's not that hard, if you're into linux, you can give it a shot). More about that, in this Unix & Linux community [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120232/dual-boot-windows-on-second-harddrive-uefi-gpt-system).

Hope this helps!